# cfdocument: open download prompt to ask user where to save pdf

Tags: pdf, cfml, cfdocument

I'm using cfdocument to create a pdf. Displaying the pdf in the browser works fine, but I would like to just open a download prompt when the user opens that url.

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" localUrl="yes" margintop="0.25" orientation="landscape">
```

What I tried:
I followed this and added a filename: https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/how-to-use-cfdocument-create-a-pdf-file-and-save-the-file-in-server/td-p/966276

But it just saves that file in a lucee temp folder.

What I want is that it opens a prompt and asks the user, where he wants to save that file.

Comment: @KJ well it would not be necessary for me to display it in the browser at all, opening a download prompt would be enough for my belongings

Comment: @KJ this was the issue. The browser settings on how to handle pdf files by default was set to always show the pdf file, instead of downloading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't prompt the "save as" directly. The cause is that nowadays most browsers save the file immediately/directly to the "download" folder by default. For example in Chrome the user can deactivate this behaviour in "`Settings -> Downloads -> Ask where to save each file before downloading`".  A similar setting exists in Firefox.

However, if you don't want to display the PDF in the browser but start a direct download, just add the http headers used for that. This is an example how to achieve it (
I've tested this on Lucee only but should work for ACF the same way):

```html
<cfheader name="Content-Transfer-Encoding" value="binary">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=""somefilename.pdf""">
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/pdf">
<cfdocument format = "PDF" pagetype="A4" orientation="portrait">
    Just a test for download!
</cfdocument>
```

If you omit the attribute `filename="somefilename.pdf"` of the Content-Disposition response header, the name of the url will be taken. Alternatively you could ask the user to specify a name in a form input field and populate that variable. But it still will be downloaded to the "download" directory as specified in the users browser setting.

Comment: While you are basically right, i want to add that even this does not download the pdf if e.g. in Google Chrome the settings for pdf is set to "display in browser" instead of downloading, which was also my problem. 
I will accept your answer as correct though, so that if someone comes across this sees your answer + this comment.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. My chrome is always set to "display in browser" for PDFs, but still the code above should download it to the users download folder without opening it. Even if a copy is already available in the download folder, the os will generate a new name with the index number added in partenthesis.